# Migration Ninject -> Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

We use `Ninject` in our project, but have some performance problems. It will be interesting to test the same project with `Simple Injector`.

Do you know some kind of guides that make the migration easier?

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? Many (more or less) advanced scenarios have no counterpart in Simple Injector, so you might have issues migrating everything. Simple scenarios can be mapped one-to-one to SimpleInjector. For example, you can't register components by name in SimpleInjector. If the performance of the container is an issue, maybe you need to revise your architecture. As an intermediate solution, consider containers like Autofac which are pretty fast but still support advanced scenarios.

Comment: "Many (more or less) advanced scenarios have no counterpart in Simple Injector, so you might have issues migrating everything. Simple scenarios can be mapped one-to-one to SimpleInjector." My question was about the guide containing such an information.

Comment: "If the performance of the container is an issue, maybe you need to revise your architecture." Maybe. Maybe not ) To test the same project with Simple Incector - its only one of many options

Comment: @AndreLoker: You named the one useless feature that other containers have but Simple Injector doesn't. I personally have never seen a good example of when named registrations are useful. Named registrations signal problems in the design. Although I must admit that some containers need to feature to be able to do what Simple Injector can do without :-)

Comment: @MikroDel: All the migration guides available at http:\\simpleinjector.codeplex.com help you migrate from Simple Injector to other containers, but not the other way around. But if you just ask here what specific problems you have with this migration and I'll show you how to do this.

Comment: @Steven I was at http:\\simpleinjector.codeplex.com thats why I ask it here ) Thanks for your proposal

Comment: As far as named registrations for simple injector read this:  https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/441049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for today there isnt such a guide for the migration `Ninject` -> `Simple Injector`.

Comment: But you can always write your findings down in a blog post and link to it from here :-)

Comment: This is on topic but not a full tutorial: Migrating from Ninject to Simple Injector https://adrianhesketh.com/2015/05/06/migrating-from-ninject-to-simple-injector/